# java stream custom summary statistics

Tags: java, java-stream

The following is a sample of a very large CSV file:

```
id, type, profit, purchaseDate, soldDate
order1, fruit, 115.50, 1/1/2020, 20/1/2020
order2, veg, 114.25, 7/1/2020, 7/2/2020
order3, flowers, 113.30, 5/1/2020, 15/1/2020
order4, fruit, 111.20, 1/1/2019, 30/1/2019
order5, veg, 112.40, 17/1/2019,10/2/2019
```

I need to read this very large file and produce the following summary of statistics:

1. item wise profits
2. year with highest orders
3. avg time between purchase and sale dates

I can do one stat at a time.I have used commons CSV parser:

```
Reader in = new FileReader("filePath");
Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                                       .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                                       .withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)
                                       .withDelimiter(',')
                                       .withTrim()
                                       .parse(in);
StreamSupport
    .stream(records.spliterator(), false)
    .collect(groupingBy(r -> r.get("type"),averagingDouble(r ->  Double.parseDouble(r.get("profit")))));
```

I am looking to see if we can get multiple stats using Java streaming api with a single sweep and without memory overload as this is a very large file.

Comment: You would have to implement a custom summary statistics mostly as the title reads already.

Comment: Since you opened up for different solutions. And that you don't need to reuse it. This sounds like a script job. jq sed and awk FTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CustomSummaryStatistics implements Consumer<Order> {

    private Map<String, BigDecimal> itemWiseProfits = new HashMap<>();
    private Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> yearWithMaxOrders;
    private int avgDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate;

    private Map<Integer, Integer> yearWiseOrdersMap = new HashMap<>();
    private long totalDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate;
    private long numRecords;

    public static Collector<Order, ?, CustomSummaryStatistics> newCollector() {
        return Collector.of(CustomSummaryStatistics::new, CustomSummaryStatistics::accept,
                CustomSummaryStatistics::combine, CustomSummaryStatistics::finisher);
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(Order order) {
        updateItemWiseProfits(order);
        updateYearWithHighestOrders(order);
        updateAvgDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate(order);
    }

    private void updateItemWiseProfits(Order order) {
        itemWiseProfits.merge(order.getItemType(), order.getTotalProfit(), BigDecimal::add);
    }

    private void updateYearWithHighestOrders(Order order) {
        yearWiseOrdersMap.merge(order.getOrderDate().getYear(), 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    private void updateAvgDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate(Order order) {
        numRecords++;
        totalDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate += Period.between(order.getOrderDate(), order.getShipDate()).getDays();
    }

    public CustomSummaryStatistics combine(CustomSummaryStatistics other) {
        other.itemWiseProfits.forEach((k, v) -> itemWiseProfits.merge(k, v, BigDecimal::add));
        other.yearWiseOrdersMap.forEach((k, v) -> yearWiseOrdersMap.merge(k, v, Integer::sum));
        numRecords += other.numRecords;
        totalDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate += other.totalDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate;
        return this;
    }

    public CustomSummaryStatistics finisher() {
        yearWithMaxOrders = yearWiseOrdersMap.entrySet().stream()
                                .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparing(entry -> entry.longValue())));
        avgDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate = (int) (totalDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate / numRecords);
        return this;
    }

    public Map<String, BigDecimal> getItemWiseProfits() {
        return itemWiseProfits;
    }

    public int getAvgDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate() {
        return avgDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate;
    }

    public Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> getYearWithMaxOrders() {
        return yearWithMaxOrders;
    }

    public long getNumRecords() {
        return numRecords;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CustomSummaryStatistics{" +
                "itemWiseProfits=" + itemWiseProfits +
                ", yearWithMaxOrders=" + yearWithMaxOrders +
                ", avgDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate=" + avgDaysBetweenOrderDateAndShipDate +
                ", numRecords=" + numRecords +
                '}';
    }
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Order {
    @NotBlank
    private String itemType;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate orderDate;
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate shipDate;
    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal totalProfit;
}

public class SalesReport {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/y");
    private static final Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CustomSummaryStatistics stats;
        try {
            stats = calculateSummaryStats("data/SalesRecords.csv");
            System.out.println(stats.toString());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Time(milli-seconds) taken to generate Sales Report : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
    }

    public static CustomSummaryStatistics calculateSummaryStats(String filePath) throws IOException {
        Reader in = new FileReader(filePath);
        Iterable<CSVRecord> iterable =
                CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                        .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
                        .withIgnoreEmptyLines(true)
                        .withDelimiter(',')
                        .withTrim()
                        .parse(in);
        return StreamSupport
                .stream(iterable.spliterator(), true)
                .map(csvRecord -> toOrder(csvRecord))
                .filter(order -> order != null)
                .collect(CustomSummaryStatistics.newCollector());
    }

    // map and validate
    public static Order toOrder(CSVRecord record) {
        Order order = new Order();
        try {
            order.setItemType(record.get("Item Type"));
            order.setOrderDate(LocalDate.parse(record.get("Order Date"), df));
            order.setShipDate(LocalDate.parse(record.get("Ship Date"), df));
            order.setTotalProfit(new BigDecimal(record.get("Total Profit")));

            //validate
            Set violations = validator.validate(order);
            if (!violations.isEmpty()) throw new Exception("Failed validation:" + violations.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error with row: " + record.toString() + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return order;
    }
}
```